# Using Azure Active Directory token in ASP.Net Core Web API with UseJwtBearerAuthenticiation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework, azure-active-directory, json-web-token

I have a native client application written in Ionic Framework 3.  I have a Web API written in ASP.NET Core 1.1.  I want to use Azure Active Directory to manage access to the Web API.

I have registered two applications with Azure Active Directory: Mobile App and Web API.  The Mobile App has the required permission of granting access to the Web API.  Below are screen shots of the permissions from our Azure Admin Portal:

[Mobile App Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04c31.png)

This is configured as a Native App in AAD.  I have an Application ID and an Object ID given by AAD.  Additionally, I added an arbitrary Redirect URI, which I thought based on several tutorials did not need to resolve, that URI is `http://mobileCRMApp`.  Looking at the Properties in AAD, the Home page URL is blank and the Logout URL is blank.

[API Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFxEU.png)

**BOLD UPDATED 10/03/2017:**

This is configured as a Web App/API in AAD.  I have an Application ID and an Object ID given by AAD.  Additionally, **I set both the Home Page URL and the App ID URI to match the root of my Web API (`https://crm.mycompany.com`)**.

My Ionic client application successfully authenticates against AAD roughly in the following way:

```
authenticate(userID, authCompletedCallback) : any {
  let parent = this;
  //this.context = new AuthenticationContext(this.config.authority);
  let context = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenantId");
  console.log(context);
  context.acquireTokenAsync(parent.config.resourceUri, parent.config.clientId, parent.config.redirectUri, userID, "")
          .then(authCompletedCallback)
          .catch((e: any) => console.log('Authentication failed', e));
}
```

The login process goes fine in the app, and the callback receives a token, and I can translate its payload using jwt.io into roughly the following:

```
{
 "aud": "https://crm.mycompany.com/",
 "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/someID/",
 "iat": 1506539211,
 "nbf": 1506539211,
 "exp": 1506543111,
 "acr": "1",
 "aio": "someOtherID",
 "amr": [
   "pwd"
 ],
 "appid": "appID",
 "appidacr": "0",
 "e_exp": 262800,
 "family_name": "Walter",
 "given_name": "Philip",
 "ipaddr": "someAddress",
 "name": "Philip Walter",
 "oid": "someOtherID",
 "onprem_sid": "someOtherID",
 "puid": "stuff",
 "scp": "user_impersonation",
 "sub": "e_X7WlAoVS2vzXm1pr3kcDOrET7czcC0f8-YRU_2DJ8",
 "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
 "tid": "ourTenantID",
 "unique_name": "pwalter@advtis.com",
 "upn": "pwalter@advtis.com",
 "uti": "RLvLlibQHESwmujVBBdlAA",
 "ver": "1.0"
}
```

So then I take the token and send it along with an http request to the API from the Ionic client app, roughly like so:

```
    let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authToken.accessToken);
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers : headers });
this.data.http.get(url, options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe((data) => {
     console.log(data);
  });
```

The API then has the following in Startup.cs

```
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            Authority = Configuration["Authentication: AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication: AzureAd:TenantId"],
            Audience = Configuration["Authentication: AzureAd:Audience"]
        });
```

So, I can log in through AAD in the client app, and I receive a token, but I still get a 401 unauthorized response from the web api when I send a request to a route with the [Authorize] tag above it.

I am obviously doing something wrong in configuring the API or the permissions.  I put this together using several different tutorials, because I could not find anything that specifically addressed my use case.  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong, or how I might troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Why does your audience say `"aud": "https://graph.windows.net"`?
It should say `"aud": "https://yourWebApi.azurewebsites.net"` or something similar.

The token you included above is only good for the [Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview), any other Azure AD protected resource will refuse it, including your Web API, since it expects the audience to match self.

`parent.config.resourceUri` is probably where you source the desired audience from:

```js
context.acquireTokenAsync(
    parent.config.resourceUri,
    ...
```

According to [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3):

> The `"aud"` (audience) claim identifies the recipients that the JWT is intended for. Each principal intended to process the JWT MUST identify itself with a value in the audience claim. **If the principal processing the claim does not identify itself with a value in the "aud" claim when this claim is present, then the JWT MUST be rejected.** In the general case, the "aud" value is an array of case- sensitive strings, each containing a StringOrURI value. In the special case when the JWT has one audience, the "aud" value MAY be a single case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI value. The interpretation of audience values is generally application specific. Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

Sometimes it's called *resource*, sometimes *audience*, sometimes *aud*... it is what it is :)

Comment: I tried changing the `parent.config.resourceUri` to the App ID URI of the Azure resource I am trying to access (the web api).  I now get a token back with the `aud` equal to my native application's `clientId`.  A request to my Web API still gets a 401 denial.  Am I going about this the right way?  I have two apps registered with Azure: nativeApp and WebAPI.  nativeApp has delegated permission to access WebAPI.  nativeApp gets a token from AAD as described above, then presents that token when making requests to WebAPI.  Is this the right flow?  If so, I must still have these URI's wrong??

Comment: Parent.config.ResourceUri should be `https://yourweb.api.com` or whatever that sits at.

Comment: I am seeing a URL now, but I'm still confused on this. Let's say my api sits at `https://crm.mycompany.com/api/` - I have other things happening in the root directory, like a web-based UI.  I register a corresponding app in Azure, which then has all of it's own URIs like App ID URI, Homepage URL, redirect URL, etc.  The actual URL of my api mentioned off the top is not in Azure anywhere, and if I put it in the request for the token, I get an error that states the user interrupted the flow.  I appreciate your help so far!  Please help me understand where I'm screwing up.

Comment: I am also confused as to how my Web API should be configured with `useJwtBearerAuthentication` I have used several different tutorials/articles to get to this point, though none have been exactly what I needed, so clearly I'm missing something critical.

Comment: I'm confused, so your Web API isn't registered with Azure AD? Maybe you should edit your question with screenshots from permissions in Azure AD since i'm a bit lost as to what's what. Also your audience should read `https://crm.mycompany.com` even if the real API sits under `/api`.

Comment: The API is registered under App Registrations in Azure as a Web App/API.  The Mobile App is also registered as Native.  The Mobile App grants delegated permissions to access the API.  When I change the audience to `http://crm.mycompany.com` I get the following error `Authentication failed Error: User cancelled the flow` - I have changed original question to include screen shots of permissions.  Thanks for sticking with me so far!

Comment: I am now getting the correct audience in my token - `https://crm.mycompany.com` - and I changed the original question to reflect the changes I made to accomplish this.  I am still getting the 401 error, however, so I the authorization setup in the API still needs tweaking.  Any other thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Make sure your `Startup.Auth.cs` look like Step 4 here - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet.md#step-2-set-up-the-app-to-use-the-owin-authentication-pipeline Also, your `aud` should have a trailing slash at the end. Not sure if you have it or you just accidentally put that in when redacting the real URL.

Comment: Yes, the trailing slash is there. I don't think I can use the OWIN pipeline as described in the article you linked, because I am running asp.net Core.

Comment: I believe this is the equivalent for .NET Core: https://gist.github.com/snobu/d0c47a2e51f98ba0db4917f41194b681. Just File->New->Project in Visual Studio and look at what gets generated for you  after you tick "Azure AD" in the wizard.

Comment: Nope, my bad, that's not it, this is the right thing: https://github.com/mspnp/architecture-center/blob/master/docs/multitenant-identity/web-api.md#authenticating-in-the-web-api -- Make sure you have the token code early in the pipeline (e.g. before you call app.UseMvc).

Comment: I changed my app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication to match the reference, and yes, it is before everything else in the pipeline, but I'm still getting the unauthorized response.  Is there a way to get more granularity from the 401 response?  Maybe that would offer more clues ...

Comment: Still hacking away at this.  I have been able to dig deeper into the response from the server using Fiddler.  It shows `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"`  Not sure at this point how to test the signature, or what to look for in the token.  I did generate a key for the MobileApp, and sent it along with the request for the token.  Still getting a token back, but nothing has changed when sending the secret_key to Azure to get the token.